# Visual Basic: Copy folder from %appdata% to a new folder

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a small script that will copy a folder (named .minecraft) to a new folder (doesn't exist, but I want to create a new folder called .minecraft_backups).
The current code I have is:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("%appdata%/.minecraft", "%appdata%/.minecraft_backups", True)
```

I get an error saying:
Could not find directory '%appdata%/.minecraft'.
I'm guessing it's because of the %appdata% shortcut. Is there any workaround to do this? The reason for this is because obviously if I don't enter %appdata% and enter the full route to the directory I need to enter the users username for the computer.

Could anyone write a tiny piece of code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to get an string representation of your environment variables.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx

Comment: I was getting really confused as to how to use it. I'm new to Visual Basic - In fact I started it about an hour ago.

I think I've got it to work. It makes a new folder at least. Thanks !! :)

Here's what I had:
`My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\.minecraft_backups"))`

Comment: No probs. Glad it was of some use.